# How can I limit my selector to a specific element related to an input?

Tags: jquery

I want the character counting code to work on multiple inputs but I can't figure out how to implement an each function on my keyup so that the `.char-count` works on the closest `.input`

```js
function checkTextAreaMaxLength(textBox, e) {
  var maxLength = parseInt($(textBox).data("length"));
  if (!checkSpecialKeys(e)) {
    if (textBox.value.length > maxLength - 1)
      textBox.value = textBox.value.substring(0, maxLength);
  }
  $(".char-count").html(maxLength - textBox.value.length);
  return true;
}
function checkSpecialKeys(e) {
  if (
    e.keyCode != 8 &&
    e.keyCode != 46 &&
    e.keyCode != 37 &&
    e.keyCode != 38 &&
    e.keyCode != 39 &&
    e.keyCode != 40
  )
    return false;
  else return true;
}

$(".input").on("keyup", function(event) {
  checkTextAreaMaxLength(this, event);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item">
    <textarea class='input' rows='3' data-length=250 data-min-rows='3'></textarea>
    <h4><span class="char-count">250</span> chars remaining</h4>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <input class='input' data-length=120/>
    <h4><span class="char-count">120</span> chars remaining</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI, `input` elements are self-closing. It's incorrect to use a two-tag syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reduce your selector using DOM traversal. There are many ways to do this. Here's one approach using an ancestor element:

```
$(textBox).closest('.item').find('.char-count').html(maxLength - textBox.value.length);
```

Another would be to use a sibling selector:

```
$(textBox).siblings().find('.char-count').html(maxLength - textBox.value.length);
```

Or, more specifically, the next element selector:

```
$(textBox).next().find('.char-count').html(maxLength - textBox.value.length);
```

I like to be a little more specific with the ancestor selector in case the interior markup structure changes. `parent()` is fragile sometimes. If you were to add a wrapper around the input for layout purposes, for example (as in when using Bootstrap), `parent()` is no longer appropriate and your script breaks. I find it more durable to target the outermost element in your markup group. The same idea is true of `siblings()` and `next()`. It's better to leave some flexibility in your selector.

```js
function checkTextAreaMaxLength(textBox, e) {
var maxLength = parseInt($(textBox).data("length"));

if (!checkSpecialKeys(e)) {
    if (textBox.value.length > maxLength - 1)
        textBox.value = textBox.value.substring(0, maxLength);
}

$(textBox).closest('.item').find('.char-count').html(maxLength - textBox.value.length);

return true;
}

function checkSpecialKeys(e) {
if (
    e.keyCode != 8 &&
    e.keyCode != 46 &&
    e.keyCode != 37 &&
    e.keyCode != 38 &&
    e.keyCode != 39 &&
    e.keyCode != 40
)
    return false;
else return true;
}

$(".input").on("keyup", function(event) {
checkTextAreaMaxLength(this, event);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
<textarea class='input' rows='3' data-length=250 data-min-rows='3'></textarea>
<h4><span class="char-count">250</span> chars remaining</h4>
</div>
<div class="item">
<input class='input' data-length=120></input>
<h4><span class="char-count">120</span> chars remaining</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The **key** is here:

```
$(textBox).parent().find('span.char-count').html(maxLength - textBox.value.length);
```

from the edited element you should go `parent()` and `find()` the `span.char-count` from the div `item`.

```js
function checkTextAreaMaxLength(textBox, e) {
  var maxLength = parseInt($(textBox).data("length"));
  if (!checkSpecialKeys(e)) {
    if (textBox.value.length > maxLength - 1)
      textBox.value = textBox.value.substring(0, maxLength);
  }
  $(textBox).parent().find('span.char-count').html(maxLength - textBox.value.length);
  return true;
}
function checkSpecialKeys(e) {
  if (
    e.keyCode != 8 &&
    e.keyCode != 46 &&
    e.keyCode != 37 &&
    e.keyCode != 38 &&
    e.keyCode != 39 &&
    e.keyCode != 40
  )
    return false;
  else return true;
}

$(".input").on("keyup", function(event) {
  checkTextAreaMaxLength(this, event);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
<textarea class='input' rows='3' data-length=250 data-min-rows='3'></textarea>
<h4><span class="char-count">250</span> chars remaining</h4>
</div>
<div class="item">
<input class='input' data-length=120></input>
<h4><span class="char-count">120</span> chars remaining</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

We can traverse to the changed input parent(s) with `item` as a selector and then `find` the `char-count` class in it.

`$(textBox).parents(".item").find(".char-count");` // Here we are traversing from input to `class="item"` div(which is the parent of input) and then we are finding `char-count` respective to that and changing its html value.

```js
function checkTextAreaMaxLength(textBox, e) {
  var maxLength = parseInt($(textBox).data("length"));
  if (!checkSpecialKeys(e)) {
    if (textBox.value.length > maxLength - 1)
      textBox.value = textBox.value.substring(0, maxLength);
  }
  $(textBox).parents(".item").find(".char-count").html(maxLength - textBox.value.length);
  return true;
}
function checkSpecialKeys(e) {
  if (
    e.keyCode != 8 &&
    e.keyCode != 46 &&
    e.keyCode != 37 &&
    e.keyCode != 38 &&
    e.keyCode != 39 &&
    e.keyCode != 40
  )
    return false;
  else return true;
}

$(".input").on("keyup", function(event) {
  checkTextAreaMaxLength(this, event);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
<textarea class='input' rows='3' data-length=250 data-min-rows='3'></textarea>
<h4><div><span class="char-count">250</span> chars remaining</h4>
</div></div>
<div class="item">
<input class='input' data-length=120></input>
<h4><span class="char-count">120</span> chars remaining</h4>
</div>
```